# Pagination in Prisma with Cursor is Slow

Tags: node.js, postgresql, prisma

I've tried both methods (cursor and offset) to paginate through my ~1000 doc DB, however, I can't get cursor to be faster than offset.

```js
// cursor method
    const allDocs = []
    let queryResults = await prismaClient.obsidian.findMany({
        take: 100
    })
    while (queryResults.length > 0) {
        allDocs.push(...queryResults)
        queryResults = await prismaClient.obsidian.findMany({
            take: 100,
            skip: 1,
            cursor: {
                id: queryResults[queryResults.length - 1]!.id
            }
        })
    }
    return allDocs
```

takes **~25 seconds to complete** (NB: also it seems to be using `OFFSET`, I thought it wasn't supposed to do that?)

```
Query: SELECT "public"."obsidian"."id", "public"."obsidian"."doc", "public"."obsidian"."createdAt", "public"."obsidian"."updatedAt", "public"."obsidian"."filename" FROM "public"."obsidian", (SELECT "public"."obsidian"."id" AS "obsidian_id_0" FROM "public"."obsidian" WHERE ("public"."obsidian"."id") = ($1)) AS "order_cmp" WHERE "public"."obsidian"."id" >= "order_cmp"."obsidian_id_0" ORDER BY "public"."obsidian"."id" ASC LIMIT $2 **OFFSET** $3
```

```js
    // offset method
    const count = await prismaClient.obsidian.count()
    const pages = Math.ceil(count / 100)
    const allDocsPromises = []
    for (let i = 0; i < pages; i++) {
        const page = prismaClient.obsidian.findMany({
            skip: i * 100,
            take: 100
        })
        allDocsPromises.push(page)
    }
    const allDocs = await Promise.all(allDocsPromises)
    return _.flatten(allDocs)
```

takes **~14 seconds to complete**. My thought is that `offset` method is running faster due to `Promise.all()` but is there a way to get cursor pagination to return all the documents super fast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prisma is using some internal mechanisms to buffer data in order to speed up and resolve N+1 problem. But in some case, it would lead to poor performance.

This is a prisma middleware to bypass it's mechanism and speed up.
If you think you are running slow, you may give it a try.

```
prisma.$use(async (params, next) => {
    if (params.args?.cursor) {
      const key = _.lowerFirst(params.model)
      const result = await prisma[key].findUniqueOrThrow({
        where: params.args.cursor,
        select: params.args.orderBy ? _(params.args.orderBy).mapValues(x => true).value() : undefined,
      })
      params.args.where = {
        ...params.args.where,
        ..._(params.args.cursor).mapValues((x, k) => ({
          [x === 'desc' ? 'lte' : 'gte']: result[k],
        })).value(),
        ..._(params.args.orderBy).mapValues((x, k) => ({
          [x === 'desc' ? 'lte' : 'gte']: result[k],
        })).value(),
      }
      delete params.args.cursor
    }
    return await next(params)
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

First, cursor based pagination does not use OFFSET, in the [doc](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/pagination#-pros-of-cursor-based-pagination) mentions that.

Second, your thought about the `Promise.all` is ok. Use `Promise.all` for parallel processing and use `for` for sequential processing (I think that the problem lies with sequential processing).

Finally, here you go a [post](https://uxdesign.cc/why-facebook-says-cursor-pagination-is-the-greatest-d6b98d86b6c0) about the benefits of cursor based pagination, enjoy it :)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 1):

What Prisma calls cursor pagination, others call 'key set' pagination.  There is no actual cursor involved.  But how efficient that is is going to be depends on the rest of the query, and on having the right index(es), neither of which we can assess with the info provided.  Since you are reading all the data into memory on a tight loop anyway, why not just read it and omit the pagination?

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It may be the way my model is structured (I'm storing very large 2D vectors in JSON), but using a findMany() times out with a GenericError. So I added pagination to fetch bits at a time to send to memory.